# Having EKCalendarChooser Issues Only When a Single Calendar Account is Present

Tags: ios, objective-c, eventkit

I'm using iOS 7.1 and doing the following to present writable calendars to the user with EventKit:

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKCalendarChooser *calendarChooser = [[EKCalendarChooser alloc] initWithSelectionStyle:EKCalendarChooserSelectionStyleMultiple displayStyle: EKCalendarChooserDisplayWritableCalendarsOnly eventStore:eventStore];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:calendarChooser animated:YES];
```

I'm noticing two very strange behaviors that only seem to happen when I'm testing against a single calendar account:

1. Tapping the accessory (highlighted in the screen below) will always cause the app to crash.
   [image]
2. If the account contains N writable calendars, only N - 1 calendars will be displayed. In the above screenshot for some reason a second writable calendar (called "Work") that's associated with this iCloud account is not being displayed.

The example above uses iCloud, but I've also tested this issue against an Exchange/Outlook account and gotten similar results.

Does it look like I'm missing something in my code? Have other developers had similar experiences?

Comment: Can you post the crash information?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
After a lot of "trial and error" I figured out,
that EKCalendarChooser must be the root view controller of an UINavigationController:

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init]; 
EKCalendarChooser *calendarChooser = [[EKCalendarChooser alloc] initWithSelectionStyle:EKCalendarChooserSelectionStyleMultiple displayStyle: EKCalendarChooserDisplayWritableCalendarsOnly eventStore:eventStore]; 
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: calendarChooser];
```

This should work. I presented this with a popover controller on iPad, but presenting it with another UINavigationController might work too.

@Apple: please update the documentation to avoid such a trouble

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to re-create the issue in iOS 7.1.2.  Maybe it was fixed?

Comment: I had the issue as I've put the EKCalendarChooser directly into a PopupController, and it was IOS8 beta, so maybe this could be a reintroduced bug too.